# Does anyone know where I can find a free efficient frontier tool, or an informative and legitamate/academic graph of the efficient frontier?

Tags: risk-management, modern-portfolio-theory, capm, standard-deviation

I'd like to build a portfolio based upon modern portfolio theory and I'd like to find a tool I can use to calculate the proper mix of asset classes. Can anyone help with this? I think a good chart/graph showing stocks, bonds, oil, etc. along the efficient frontier would suffice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PerformanceAnalytics in R and PortfolioAnalytics in R

Here is a tutorial from UW http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioFunctionsPowerPoint.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are two good tools in R project: Systematic Investor Toolbox and fPortfolio package.

Comment: Systematic Investor Toolbox masks base R functions, I would recommend against it.

Comment: I second Kyle's recommendation against. It has some interesting and valuable concepts, but the implementation is shaky.